# UIImagePickerController crashes when video button is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, camera

Following code works good when capturing photo using camera, but app crashes when user taps on video.

```
 let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
 imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
 imagePicker.delegate = self
 if let _ = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .camera) {
     imagePicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .camera)!
     if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
         imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
         present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem and it was due to not asking for microphone usage permission in my `Info.plist`.

Check that you have a proper value for:

- `NSCameraUsageDescription` (`Privacy - Camera Usage Description`)
- `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` (`Privacy - Microphone Usage Description`)
- `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` (`Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`)

Then when you change from *photo* mode to *video* mode your app will ask for microphone access instead of just crashing.

Comment: Very much appreciated !

Comment: thanks, this list is really useful because Xcode throws an exception but doesn't show what is going wrong